# Is It Appropriate to Provide a Professor's Assistant's Email in the Application System?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, recommendation-letter

I'm currently in the process of applying to a graduate program and have a question regarding the submission of recommendation letters.

I have a professor who has agreed to provide a recommendation letter for me. However, due to his busy schedule, much of their correspondence, including matters related to recommendations, is often managed by his lab administrative assistant.

My question is: In the application, is it acceptable to provide the details (name, position. etc.) of the professor as the recommender but use the assistant's email address (uni email, ofc) for correspondence? This arrangement is with the understanding that the recommendation letter is authored by the professor, but the assistant handles the submission.
How might an admissions committee react to this arrangement? Is there a chance it could be viewed unfavorably?

Comment: Is this what the professor has told you to do? Usually a PA would have access to the professor's email account, precisely so that this kind of thing is not necessary.

Comment: I would assume that the admissions committee may well not even see what email address you entered into the system, only the resulting recommendation letter, no matter which email address it was sent in from. Probably best to just ask the recommending professor, or their assistant as to what they usually do if you don't want to bother the professor.

Comment: @avid I wasn't told how to do it and I don't think that the PA has access to the email.